# How can I put a lot of data in android application?

Tags: android

My question is how can I put a lot of data in android application,or what is the best way to solve my problem ?

***I'm building an app that will contain about 43 lessons,every lesson will be accessed through cardview and every lesson will have a lot of text,images and maybe some other things.***

Is the best way to solve this to do every lesson manually,or there is another way that I could solve this.

[This is how lessons should look like in cardview (similar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN5dP.png)

And when i click on cardview needs to display me a lesson.
My problem is only text,image and other things in that lesson.

Comment: You can display the data using a recyclerView. Not sure what else seems to be the problem? 43 items even containg lots of text shouldn't really be a proble

Comment: So the best way to do this is to make layout file for every lesson and write lesson manually ?

Comment: You probably need some kind of database to store the lessons, i wouldnt write a layout for every lesson, but write a cardview layout, and then using a recyclerview display every lesson like that, then when a user clicks a lesson get detailed information about that one

Comment: You need to store all your data in a database and populate your contents in a recycler list. I have a project in github that might help you https://github.com/mbobiosio/SqliteDatabaseAssets and this is the Kotlin version https://github.com/mbobiosio/WordCup18Team

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all your data in a database and populate your contents in a recycler list. With this you can click on each item to view a particular lesson.

- You will eliminate the need to create multiple activities for each lesson.
- You will have a small app size

I have a project in github that might help you https://github.com/mbobiosio/SqliteDatabaseAssets and this is the Kotlin version https://github.com/mbobiosio/WordCup18Team

Comment: I think this is what I need.

Thanks,I will check your project.